# Jar Lib on Android Project And Android APP

Tags: java, android, gradle

I create a Jar Lib called "errors" in Java. 
I would like to use it in a module called "AndroidHTTPRequestLibrairy" and in my Android App.

But i have a error :

**Program type already present:**

In my module (AndroidHTTPRequestLibrairy) build.gradle i have :

**implementation files('libs/errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar')**

And in my app I have :

**implementation project(path: ':androidhttprequestlibrairy')**

and

**implementation files('libs/errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar')**

I dont understand why.

Can someone help me ?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears because of namespace conflict.

You are trying to put one library twice in one project. When the Gradle build your project and at the moment when it tries to put in your app.apk archive the errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar library it finds out that there is already the errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar library and throws an exception.

So the solutions is to remove the `implementation files('libs/errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar')` dependency form the application **build.gradle** file, because it allready transited in the `implementation project(path: ':androidhttprequestlibrairy')` dependency

Comment: Indeed, when i remove implementation files('libs/errors-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar'), i just have to change in my project androidhttprequestlibrairy to change implementation to api
Thank a lot